# Python - Time inputs and adding/subtracting

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am trying to take user input in 24h time and then do calculations (adding hours, subtracting hours, etc) to those inputs.  I have something as follows:

```
# get start time
start_t = int(input("Start time: "))
print(start_t)

# get stop time
stop_t = int(input("Stop time: "))
print(stop_t)
```

The issues are:

1. when I print the times, if there is a leading zero (e.g. `0200`), it prints `200`.
2. When I try and do any sort of addition or subtraction, it is not displaying correctly. For example if I enter the stop time at `2200`, and I want the calculated time to be `stop_t - 8` (hours), it displays `0`. I would like it to display `0000`. The other thing I notice is if I do `stop_t - 8`, it displays `2192`. I have to do `stop_t - 800` to get the `0`. This seems like the wrong way to approach this.

I'd imagine there is some sort of `datetime` I have to do to make this work, but thus far my searches have come up empty handed.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: "I'd imagine there is some sort of datetime I have to do to make this work, but thus far my searches have come up empty handed." => Err, really ??? That's __very__ surprising, to say the least, since "datetime" is the exact name of the stdlib module handling dates and times, so googling for "python datetime" should _certainly_ yield something...

Comment: I think that this page might give you a good start: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior
You can basically read in a string, convert it to a `datetime` object with `strptime()` and then use `timedelta()` to make adjustments. Hope this helps!

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - what I was saying is that my searches revealed there was some sort of datetime function utilization I need to use, but I hadn't been able to successfully make it work.  Perhaps I should have made that more clear.    I'm still working on trying to figure this out, but I think I'm getting closer.

Answer (score 2):

The `input()` method can only take text from the terminal.

You have to parse the text into a `datetime` object to manipulate it.

For example:

```py
import datetime

time_format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S" # example 01-01-2019 23:00:00

# get start time
start_time_input = input("Start time:")
print(start_time_input)

# get stop time
stop_time_input = input("Stop time:")
print(stop_time_input)

# conversion
start_t = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_time_input, time_format)
print(start_t)
stop_t = datetime.datetime.strptime(stop_time_input, time_format)
print(stop_t)
```

if `start_time_input` or `stop_time_input` do not respect `time_format` format, you get a `ValueError` exception.

When you have `datetime` objects you can do a lot of stuff, for example, subtractions

```py
import datetime
start_t = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-2019 22:00:00", time_format)
stop_t = datetime.datetime.strptime("01-01-2019 23:00:00", time_format)
time_difference = stop_t - start_t
print(time_difference)
# output is 1:00:00
```

for more functions see datetime libs https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html